# Change Default action base on user groups in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I have different users groups e.g. admin, author,publisher and have separately controllers for them  I want to set default path after login on base of

> $this->Auth->User('group_id')

like this in appcontroller in beforefilter() method

```
if ($this->Auth->User('group_id') == '1')
        {
            Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'index'));
        } 
elseif($this->Auth->User('group_id') == '2')
        {
            Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'author', 'action' => 'index'));
        } 
else {
            Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'publisher', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
```

I tried this in

> routes.php

in Config using $_SESSION Variable because in that file couldnt use
$this.
Main purpose is that when user login it will take to their controller and so i can have clean URL
I dont want to same controller i have to use check for group than ACL library's power will be in waste.
Any Help will be appreciated to accomplish this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment on Isaac's answer, you can do something like this.
Say, in routes.php you can have:

```
Route::connect('/', array('controller' => 'some_controller', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Then in your redirected controller's `index()` method:

```
public function index() 
{
    $group = $this->User->Group->find('first', array( //assuming User belongsTo Group
        'conditions' => array(
            'id' => $this->Auth->User('group_id')
        ),
        'fields' => array('name')
        )
    )); //getting the name of the group the user belongs to

    call_user_func(array($this, strtolower($group['Group']['name']).'_index'));

}
```

And then in your controller you can have something like:

```
protected function admin_index()
{
    //code for admins
}

protected function publisher_index()
{
    //code for publishers
}

protected function author_index()
{
    //code for authors
}
```

So you have all code on the same controller but separated on different methods.

Comment: It seemed best approach till now but is there possibility `Route::connect('/'` I can change default controller for each user group ?

Answer (score 0):

//Don't miss the app_controller for this small kind of thing. bear in mind always keep the app controller clean and tidy.

```
function login(){
    //here you can say after login what's happen next
    if ($this->Auth->login()){
          $this->redirectUser();
    }

}

//redirect user groups
function redirectUser(){
    $role = $this->Auth->User('group_id');

    switch ($role) {
        case 1:
              return $this->redirect(array('controllers'=>'admin_controller', 'action'=>'action_name')); 
                 break;
        case 2:
              return $this->redirect(array('controllers'=>'author_controller', 'action'=>'action_name'));
        default:
              return $this->redirect(array('controllers'=>'user_controller', 'action'=>'action_name'));
                 break;
         }
}
```

If you want to use custom url You also need to name it into routes.php

```
Route::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'admin_controller', 'action' => 'index'));
```

the rest of links

Comment: It will get job done but my URL will be like this eg. www.example.com/admin , www.example.com/author etc I dont want to show each user group controller name in URL after login , How can I achieve this.

Comment: first make your Routes in Route file and then follow this

Comment: Can I change default controller for each user group after login.. ?

Comment: sure u can. by doing this you can tell to each type of user. after login which page they will be redirect to